# XHR при GET-запросе выдаёт html вместо json

Tags: ajax, reactjs, xhr

Может проблема в пути? Подскажите пожалуйста
Вот что выводит вместо json

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <head>\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta\n      name=\"viewport\"\n      content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no\"\n    />\n    <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#000000\" />\n    <link rel=\"manifest\" href=\"/manifest.json\" />\n    <title>React App</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>\n    <div id=\"root\"></div>\n  <script src=\"/static/js/bundle.js\"></script><script src=\"/static/js/0.chunk.js\"></script><script src=\"/static/js/main.chunk.js\"></script><script src=\"/main.7f626ed1f0be40d5076c.hot-update.js\"></script></body>\n</html>\n
```

```html
export const getClients = () => dispatch => {
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "./clients.json", true);
  req.send();
  req.onload = () => {
    const clientList = JSON.stringify(req.responseText);
    console.log(clientList);
    dispatch({
      type: "GET_CLIENTS",
      payload: clientList
    });
  };
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема однозначно в пути. Файлы которые находятся в src не попадают в бандл приложения при запуске, если не прописаны соответствующие правила в webpack. Для того чтобы обратится к файлу надо чтобы он попал в состав приложения ( например assets).
Обращение по относительному пути будет отталкиваться от базового href который поумолчанию / то-есть папка где лежит index.html после сборки приложения

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема решена.